# How to solve polynomial of degree 4?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I'm beginner in learning algebra and there is a question which came into my mind that how to find value of x in this type of equation -- >

**$x^4 + x^3 + x = 3$**

I know that one of its answer will  be 1,but I was wondering how to solve it through equation form.
Please help.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Solutions to a quartic equation are available. But usually you evaluate $x_0=1$ or $x_0=-1$ to see if it is a solution. Then you factor out $(x-x_0)$ to reduce the order.

Comment: show that $x=1$ is one solution and after this divide the polynomial by $x-1$

Comment: Unless you can use formula for cubic equation I don't think you can solve any further then $x=1$

Comment: Seems like $1$ is only integral solution. Do you want non-integral solutions too? Otherwise I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 3):

We have $$x^4+x^3+x=3\to x^4+x^3+x-3=0$$
$$\text{When we have powers of $x>3$, we usually find an easy solution by testing a few values.}$$
$$\text{For example, if we plug in $x=1$, we have $1+1+1-3=0$}$$
$$\text{This means that $x=1$ is one of the solutions, and that $(x-1)$ is factor.}$$

Now we could use *synthetic division* to further reduce our polynomial. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bZoMz1Cy1T4

That will give us $x^3+2x^2+2x+3=0$

This is irrational roots, and so we cannot do much after this. Either you must use a calculator, use methods like Newton's method, or analyse the derivative and do it. There is no easy way after this.

$x=-1.81,1$

Answer (score 0):

So,
I'm assuming here that $x$ is integer because integer solution would be easier to find and work out.
$$x^4 + x^3 + x = 3$$
$$\implies x^3(x+1)+x=3$$
$$\implies x^3(x+1)+(x+1)=4$$
$$\implies (x^3+1)(x+1)=4$$
Here,
$$(x^3+1)(x+1)=2\times2$$
Thus, by comparing:
$x^3+1=2$, and, $x+1=2$.
So, $x=1$ is the only integral answer.
Also note that there might be other non-integral real answers.